# How to create a browser in asp.net 2010 ASPX page not a form

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Hi people am trying to find out is there any way to create a web browser in a vb.net aspx page rather a vb.net form. I have looked on the internet they all seem to be on a form and not a website. The reason I want it on a website is so that i can view other website pages on the website that I am creating for holding game information. For example a user is interested in finding information about a certain game within my website and instead of using another tab or opening another browser page he/she can just use the inbuilt browser on my wbesite.

Thank you

If there is any more information you like please ask me

Comment: Them tags are fine there is no need to change them

Comment: the 'vb' tag is being retired because it is ambiguous. questions should be tagged one of 'vb.net', 'vb6', 'vbscript', or 'vba'. Anything else is not going to help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can not open a browser inside a webform. It works in the other way. You open web pages inside the browser.

If you want to show some other websites, you can probably use an iframe in your web page.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp